Confusion in making duaa for something
Assalamualaikum
If I'm making duaa to marry a person and I get a thought in my mind that "maybe Allah might not help me marry this person because this person is a bit less involved into deen". But I want this person so much that I make a duaa that "Ya Allah bring this person onto deen and help me marry him " . So can I make this duaa? Or if I'm making this duaa then Allah will punish me?? Please answer this cuz I'm very confused. I get these thoughts that maybe Allah didn't want to make me marry this person because he was not on deen and I'm making a wrong duaa to bring him on deen and then marry him. I feel I'm making a duaa to change his will NAAUZUBILLAH. I know nobody can change his will. I don't know what's happening to me. These things give me a lot of anxiety because I feel I'm making a wrong duaa and Allah might punish me by not accepting(Allah forbid, Naauzubillah, I know this is wrong to think and we should think positive of Allah, I do think positive of him). Please answer this. I get similar thoughts when I'm making duaa for other things as well. May Allah bless you and all the readers. And please pray that ALLAH subhanahu wa ta'ala help me marry this person. AMEEN, ALLAHUMMA AMEEN

Making all of HIS Creation deen again is the main purpose of HIM sending Prophets. So this part of your question is obvious: praying for people to get inner truth and rightfulness cannot be wrong. Your other question, if this man is for you, I cannot answer.

Praying to Allah for a common person to get back into the right way is never wrong ... only if you ask Allah for forgiveness (or repent) for someone who has become His enemy, that would be wrong according to Quran as Allah has told us the story of Ibrahim PBUH praying for his uncle.
Another point is about your real intention for such a dua. For example parents always pray Allah to take care of their children, to keep them safe from wrong-doings, and to let them repent if they have done something wrong, and etc. and the intention for such Dua's is the love they have to their children, not explicitly for their own benefit (like for example not because I love to be known as the father of such a great child). But you seemingly pray Allah for him not because he needs this guidance, but because you need him and this seems to you to be the only way to reach him. But anyway, even if it is so, there is still no problem with that prayer, but if you could alter your intention and hand your situation to Allah, relying on him (توکل), that perhaps would be better, and He knows both of you and your futures better than yourselves:

عَسَيٰ أَنْ تَكْرَهُوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ خَيْرٌ لَكُمْ وَ عَسَيٰ أَنْ
تُحِبُّوا شَيْئًا وَ هُوَ شَرٌّ لَكُمْ وَ اللَّهُ يَعْلَمُ وَ أَنْتُمْ
لَا تَعْلَمُونَ
perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love
a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not


Asalamu alaykum wa rahmatullahu wa barakatuh sister. First of all, I don’t believe anything you are doing is wrong. You are not making dua for anything haram, and it is okay to make dua for someone to get closer to the deen (pretty sure the prophet SAWS did for his uncle Abu Talib, but I could be mistaken). No, Allah will not punish you for making this dua. I feel like you are overthinking. However, a better dua may be “O Allah, if this person will be good for me and strengthen my relationship with you, then help me marry him”. Also, when making dua remember to first send praises to Allah and then send salawat on the prophet SAWS. Then ask Allah for anything you wish. If I have said anything wrong, may Allah forgive me. I wish you the best in your endeavors, sister. Salam.
